# I can't work out why my SOAP request isn't working

Tags: xml, post, soap, postman

I'm trying to post a SOAP request using POSTMAN, and I keep getting 400 bad request.

I am posting to an iis .svc that I can access. Is there anything obvious in my code that should stop it from working?

In my headers I have Content-Type as `text/xml`, and have tried adding an empty SOAPAction, and I am using POST.

I've been messing with it for a while and have no idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header>
        <ns0:AuthHeader xmlns:ns0="http://Test.Info.SoapHeader.Authentication"> 
            <Username>testusername</Username>
            <Password>testPassword</Password>
        </ns0:AuthHeader> 
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ns0:TestApp xmlns:ns0="http://Test.Schemas.Request" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <HEADER>
            <URN_TS>2018-02-16T08:54:22</URN_TS>
            <URN_TS_END>2018-02-16T16:40:30.213</URN_TS_END>
          </HEADER>
          <EVENT>
            <EVENT_CONTACT_TYPE>Test</EVENT_CONTACT_TYPE>
            <EVENT_NATURE>Loss</EVENT_NATURE>
            <EVENT_SUBJECT>Goods Plan</EVENT_SUBJECT>
            <EVENT_TYPELIST>
              <EVENT_TYPEITEM>
                <EVENT_TYPE>Test Request</EVENT_TYPE>
              </EVENT_TYPEITEM>
            </EVENT_TYPELIST>
            <EVENT_WHO>Client</EVENT_WHO>
            <EVENT_INPUT_SOURCE>Client</EVENT_INPUT_SOURCE>
            <EVENT_SOURCE_REFERENCE>123abc</EVENT_SOURCE_REFERENCE>
            <EVENT_PROMNO>92131</EVENT_PROMNO>
            <EVENT_SEGNO>6</EVENT_SEGNO>
            <EVENT_USERID>joe</EVENT_USERID>
            <EVENT_SOURCE>bloggs</EVENT_SOURCE>
            <EVENT_NOTES>Call not logged</EVENT_NOTES>
            <EVENT_INPUT_REFERENCE xsi:nil="true" />
            <EVENT_WEBFNDOTHDESC xsi:nil="true" />
            <EVENT_PAGE_NAME xsi:nil="true" />
            <EVENT_SEARCH_ADDRESS1 xsi:nil="true" />
            <EVENT_FRAUD_IND xsi:nil="true" />
          </EVENT>
          <CLIENTLIST>
            <CLIENT>
              <CLIENT_SEQUENCE>6</CLIENT_SEQUENCE>
              <CLIENT_TYPE>Resource</CLIENT_TYPE>
              <CLIENT_TITLE>Mr</CLIENT_TITLE>
              <CLIENT_SURNAME>Test</CLIENT_SURNAME>
              <CLIENT_INITIALS xsi:nil="true" />
              <CLIENT_FIRSTNAME>Test</CLIENT_FIRSTNAME>
              <CLIENT_SECONDNAME xsi:nil="true" />
              <CLIENT_THIRDNAME xsi:nil="true" />
              <CLIENT_SEX>M</CLIENT_SEX>
              <CLIENT_MARITAL_STATUS xsi:nil="true" />
              <CLIENT_ADDRESSLIST>
                <CLIENT_ADDRESS>
                  <CLIENT_ADDRESS_TYPE>Home</CLIENT_ADDRESS_TYPE>
                  <CLIENT_ADDRESS1>Line 1</CLIENT_ADDRESS1>
                  <CLIENT_ADDRESS2>Line 2</CLIENT_ADDRESS2>
                  <CLIENT_ADDRESS3>Line 3</CLIENT_ADDRESS3>
                  <CLIENT_POSTCODE>wf99 2up</CLIENT_POSTCODE>
                </CLIENT_ADDRESS>
              </CLIENT_ADDRESSLIST>
              <CLIENT_TELEPHONELIST>
                <CLIENT_TELEPHONE>
                  <CLIENT_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_TYPE>HOME</CLIENT_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_TYPE>
                  <CLIENT_TELEPHONE_NUMBER>0123456789</CLIENT_TELEPHONE_NUMBER>
                  <CLIENT_TELEPHONE_PREFERRED_INDICATOR>Y</CLIENT_TELEPHONE_PREFERRED_INDICATOR>
                </CLIENT_TELEPHONE>
              </CLIENT_TELEPHONELIST>
              <CLIENT_PREFERRED_MARKETING_METHOD xsi:nil="true" />
            </CLIENT>
          </CLIENTLIST>
          <PRESALE>
            <PS_DATEOFAPP>2018-02-16</PS_DATEOFAPP>
          </PRESALE>
          <ADDITIONAL_INFOLIST>
            <ADDITIONAL_INFO>
              <ADD_TYPE>Joe</ADD_TYPE>
              <ADD_QUESTION>123</ADD_QUESTION>
              <ADD_ANSWER>No</ADD_ANSWER>
            </ADDITIONAL_INFO>
          </ADDITIONAL_INFOLIST>
        </ns0:TestApp>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your Postman Console log say? It might give you more information rather than just a 400 error.